# Remove <!--Zero or more repetitions:--> from soap request

Tags: web-services, soap, soapui

I'm trying to remove a comment message from a soap request.

I'm using SoapUI to do it, and I would like to remove this message and have a request page "clear" without comments.

The comment is `<!--Zero or more repetitions:-->`

How can I do it? Someone can help me? :)

Thanks

Comment: You could use a regular expression to match all comments and remove them.  Are you limited to using only SOAP UI at the moment?

Comment: I'm forced to use soapUI :)

Comment: You should download a text editor such as Notepad++ or TextPad which has regex capabilities and do the cleanup there.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to do so is using `regex` as @TimBiegeleisen note in his comment. You can do it for example using a groovy. To illustrate what I'm telling in you can do something like:

```
def xml = '''
<foo>
    <!-- some comment -->
    <bar>data</bar>
    <!-- 
        multiline comment
        multiline comment
    -->
</foo>'''

println xml.replaceAll( "(?s)<!--.*?-->", "" )
```

In the *SOAPUI* context, you've to add a *Groovy Script* testStep. There get the testStep by name, read the request, remove the comments, and  finally set the result as a request of your *testStep* again. Something like may works:

```
// get the testStep in your TestCase by name
def testStep = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName('TestStepName')
// get the request content
def request = testStep.getPropertyValue('request')
// remove comments
request = request.replaceAll( "(?s)<!--.*?-->", "" )
// update the request
testStep.setPropertyValue('request',request)
```

Hope it helps,